# Display toast when running a trigger function

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to display a toast from a triggered function? I have attempted the following, but it didn't work:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('refreshFunc')
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(6)
    .create();
}

function refreshFunc(){
  // this doesn't work
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Done", " Refresh");
}
```

Comment: BTW that's a great way to generate quota issues with the use of timebased triggers because your going to create a lot of time based triggers.  I wouldn't recommend doing that.  I would consider checking to see if there already is a trigger for that handle before creating another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
e.source.toast('Hi this was an onEdit Trigger');

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Done" + "," +"  Refresh"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that doesn't work on the refreshFunc since it doesn't have a "source" attribute?

Comment: of course not that will only work on onEdit you would need `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Done" + ","  +"  Refresh"));`

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but since I am running the function from a trigger the toast function doesn't work. It is not displayed on the open spreadsheet.

Comment: Okay I missed the point.  Because their is no ui.